# How to select all multiple spaces except last two before a specific character with a Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is an example string:

```
   Lorem ipsum   
         - dolor sit amet consectetur      
    - adipisicing elit. Adipisci, quam.
```

What would be the most elegant regex to select all extra spaces EXCEPT for two spaces before the "-" to make an elegant list?

Here is an example desired result:

```
Lorem ipsum
  - dolor sit amet consectetur
  - adipisicing elit. Adipisci, quam.
```

Here is my best guess: `/ {2,}(?! {2}-)/g.`
Sadly, it also selects the two spaces before the "-".

Edit:
I think I'll go with the folowwing:

```
let str = `       Lorem ipsum   
             - dolor sit amet consectetur      
        - adipisicing elit. Adipisci, quam.   `;
str = str.replace(/ {2,}/g, "");
str = str.replace(/-/g, "  -");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: do you need to use regex?

Comment: @depperm Not really, just looking for the most elegant solution.

Comment: like `(?<= ) (?!-)` ?

Comment: @brazoayeye Almost, we still get a space before Lorem and after ipsum and consectetur :)

Comment: what about `(?<=^) +| +(?=\n|$| (?!-))` ? I'm not very sure about brackets for | operator, but with an online tester it seems working

Comment: @brazoayeye This one works perfectly, very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could select all spaces or tabs from the start and the end of the string and replace them with an empty string. Then replace the strings that start with a hyphen with 2 spaces.

```js
const regex = /^[\t ]+|[\t ]+$/mg;
const str = `   Lorem ipsum
         - dolor sit amet consectetur
    - adipisicing elit. Adipisci, quam. `;
const subst = ``;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst).replace(/^-/gm, "  -");
console.log(result);
```

You could also you a combination of map and trim:

```js
let str = `   Lorem ipsum
         - dolor sit amet consectetur
    - adipisicing elit. Adipisci, quam. `;
str = str.split("\n").map(s => s.trim()).map(x => x.replace(/^-/, "  -")).join("\n");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: the whitespace after Lorem ipsum is still there

Comment: there is still whitespace at the end of each line

Comment: @depperm Forgot to remove the spaces from the `subst` Now they are gone.

Comment: @depperm Now they are indented. I have added another option using map and trim.

Answer (score 1):

```
(^( +)[a-zA-Z])|(( +)(( {2}-)|\n|$))
```

- `(^( +)[a-zA-Z])`: This group matches the characters before `Lorem Ipsum`.
- `(( +)(( {2}-)|\n|$))` This group matches the characters before two spaces and a `-`, or before a newline `\n`, or before the end of string `$`.

https://regex101.com/r/i4ppG7/5

Comment: what about the other whitespace?

Comment: @depperm when using a simple space and not `\s` it doesn't take newline character into account, so it is not a problem. See the link.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the newline, the OP said all the whitespace, in his post there are spaces after Lorem Ipsum

Comment: @depperm You're right, fixed it. It seems he doesn't want to target white spaces between words in the text so I simply targeted the ones before `\n`. Group 1 in the regex101 example should fit all his requirements.

Comment: edited to also match the characters before `Lorem Ipsum`.

Comment: You can modify including $ like `(^( +)[a-zA-Z])|(( +)(( {2}-)|\n|$))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing group

```js
let str = `Lorem ipsum   
        - dolor sit amet consectetur      
  - adipisicing elit. Adipisci, quam.  `

let finalList = str.replace(/^\s*(\s{2}.*)$/gm, '$1')

console.log('original list\n',str)
console.log('New list\n',finalList)
```

Comment: the whitespace after Lorem ipsum is still there